# Uses of $\pi$ value in trignometery

Tags: trigonometry

We use $\pi = 180$ degree in radian and degree relation why we not use the value of $\pi = 3.14$ in degree and radian relation? confused

Comment: The value of $\pi$ is *not* $3.14$.

Comment: Pi is a Greek letter used to denote the ratio of a circle's circumference and diameter; pie is a type of cake.

Comment: Are you just asking about units?  A foot is twelve inches.  Similarly, $\pi$ radians is $180$ degrees.   We could define other units by whatever ratio we like.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Pie is not cake...

Comment: @David: I guess it's a cultural thing. In Israel it's considered a cake. At least things like an apple pie and the likes of it. Shepherd's pie is not a cake, that is true.

Comment: Not pie-related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951021/why-in-calculus-the-angles-are-measured-in-radians/1951111#1951111

Answer (score 1):

Radians are just a unit that we use to measure angles with.  It's about 60 degrees. ($\approx57$)

Degrees are another unit used to measure angles. It is much smaller than a radian. Radians and degrees can be thought of like meters and inches.

And just like $39.4$ inches and $1$ meter represent the same length, $\pi$ (the number 3.14...) radians and 180 degrees represent the same angle.  $\pi$ still represents the number 3.14... when dealing with radians. It is just set up so that that many radians and 180 degrees are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference between

1 ) $\pi = 180°$

and

2 ) $\pi$ radians $= 180°$

1) is wrong.